# Correct the irregular border/outline of a shape

Tags: css, border

I have created 3 circles via css (:after) and with some background colors the border looks irregular. Any ideas how to fix it?

Here you can see the issue: https://flowersliving.com/cpt_01/articolo-con-colori

Below the post title, the first blue circle border.

Answer (score 0):

The blue and yellow circle has set the border but the third one has no border. When I set the border to 0 for all three circles, it looked fine.

Comment: Now also the third one has 1px solid #fff border.
I need circles with 1px border and a shadow...
As you can see, the first and the third ones have an horrible outline...